# REUSE storage functionality in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have oracle command:

```
Truncate table employee_t reuse storage;
```

This command will truncate the table and reserve the space for the future.

I am trying to implement the same in SQL SERVER, but unable to find the exact replica of that.

Can anyone please help heave?

I was trying to implement the DB Shrink, but I doubt this will work as this shrink will happen on a database level of database files level not a specified table.

Comment: Why? You should to need to do this…

Comment: Need to implement similar REUSE STORAGE of ORACLE functionality in SQL SERVER

Comment: You can't, there is no equivalent in SQL Server, apart from `delete from TableName`, but I don't think you'll like it. Why it's so important for you to reserve empty space for the table?

Comment: When asking questions about translating commands from one system to another like this, it's useful to include a summary of what the command does, since some people will have experience with SQL Server but none with Oracle. It also helps avoid the "X/Y Problem" - where your actual problem is X, but you ask about Y because that's what you expected the solution to be.

Comment: We are moving from Oracle to SQL server and we need this functionality to be implemented in SQL server.

Comment: My position is that you **don't** "need" the same functionality because it's not something a well-designed system should ever need to use - we're trying to help you here by identifying some underlying problem in your system.

Comment: Okay Okay....got it. So there is no equivalent to this REUSE in SQL server and it is not necessary to have this functionality right?

Comment: If you can explain more clearly *why* you want this functionality, perhaps someone can explain more clearly what you should be doing instead.

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` deallocates the pages in SQL Server and marks them as unused and available for new data. There is no concept of reserving pages for reuse in SQL Server, so another table or index might end up using the pages, but this shouldn't be a problem. The main takeaway is that the database *file* will not end up smaller as a result of releasing the pages, so in that sense the pages are "reserved for reuse" as the database will not have to be grown to insert more data. Shrinking files is the one thing you should never do (at least not on a regular basis) if you want to keep performance.

Comment: "So there is no equivalent to this REUSE in SQL server and it is not necessary to have this functionality right?" Correct. If you have a use case to dedicate space for a particular table and its indexes in SQL Server, you could create a filegroup dedicated for the object. Never had a reason to do that myself.